# Does the Kotlin compiler compile java files?

Tags: java, kotlin

I have a project with both .java and .kt files. Does the Kotlin compiler compiles both .java and .kt files or does it only compile my .kt files?

Comment: You could use Maven or Gradle to compile both in one project

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No, `kotlinc` compiles only Kotlin files (`.kt`).  A mixed-language project requires combining both `kotlinc` and `javac`.  If the references flow only one way, e.g., if Java code references Kotlin code and not the other way around, then the compilation order is pretty easy to figure out.  In that situation, you would compile the Kotlin code first, then include the output in the classpath to `javac` when compiling the Java code.

If the two are more intertwined, it becomes a little more complicated.  Looking at [this thread](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/compiling-mixed-java-and-kotlin-files-on-the-command-line/1553/2), it appears you'll need to run `kotlinc` first, passing in any referenced Java source files (as the `.class` files won't be available yet).  The class files built by `kotlinc` can then be included in the classpath when you compile your Java files.

Comment: Another question: Does the Kotlin compiler compile my Kotlin files to Java bytecode or is there Kotlin bytecode as well? And do you know any good books about it?

Comment: Both Java and Kotlin compile to the same type of bytecode, the JVM bytecode.

Answer (score 1):

By itself it does not, however one of the requirements to run the Kotlin compiler (according to its documentation https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin) is the JDK, so if you have Kotlin you also have `javac`