# How to add kotlin source files to my java gradle groovy project? (NOT android)

Tags: java, kotlin, gradle, groovy

I have a build.gradle in groovy, for a Java project. I have kotlin sources somewhere else. How can I add those sources to my java project?

Comment: Just apply Gradle plugin to your project.     https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm

Comment: @daggett I was able to make the kotlin part compile. The kotlin file has `package a.b;`, but doing `import a.b` on the Java main did not work. How should I do it? I did `sourceSets { 
    main.java.srcDirs += 'my_folder' 
} ` and `my_kotlin_file.kt` is inside `my_folder`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49602284/does-the-kotlin-compiler-compile-java-files#:~:text=No%2C%20kotlinc%20compiles%20only%20Kotlin,combining%20both%20kotlinc%20and%20javac%20.

Answer (score 0):

In `build.gradle`,

Change

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'maven-publish'
}
```

to

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'maven-publish'
    id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm" version "1.6.20-RC2"
}
```

then add the kotlin sources also

```
sourceSets { 
    main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
}
```

Don't forget to respect the `my/package/file.kt` where `file.kt` has `package my.package`. So, the file must be in the folder path like this.

On java you can simply import like this:

```
import my.package.*;
```

If your kotlin compiles but you get import errors, then try to verify the folder where the kotlin file is, it's likely a problem with this path. I think the difference from Java is that the file does nothave to follow the name of the class.

Answer (score 0):

## Method relying on Android Studio

Starting with a project without Kotlin plugins enabled.

1. Move all Kotlin files outside the project.
2. Quit and reopen Android Studio.
3. Create a new Kotlin file inside Android Studio.
4. There should be a popup prompt to the bottom right of Android Studio to configure for Kotlin.
   [image: Popup prompt to configure for Kotlin]
5. Expand that prompt and click the option.
   [image]
6. Follow the process Android Studio provides.
7. Try building the app. I got an error (you are all good if you have no errors).

```
2 issues were found when checking AAR metadata:

  1.  Dependency 'androidx.core:core:1.12.0-alpha01' requires libraries and applications that
      depend on it to compile against codename "UpsideDownCake" of the
      Android APIs.

      :app is currently compiled against android-33.

      Recommended action: Use a different version of dependency 'androidx.core:core:1.12.0-alpha01',
      or set compileSdkPreview to "UpsideDownCake" in your build.gradle
      file if you intend to experiment with that preview SDK.

  2.  Dependency 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.12.0-alpha01' requires libraries and applications that
      depend on it to compile against codename "UpsideDownCake" of the
      Android APIs.

      :app is currently compiled against android-33.

      Recommended action: Use a different version of dependency 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.12.0-alpha01',
      or set compileSdkPreview to "UpsideDownCake" in your build.gradle
      file if you intend to experiment with that preview SDK.
```

8. To fix the above, go to the `build.gradle` with

```
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:+'
```

and change it to use a stable version

```
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.9.0'
```

9. `Sync now` and build again. Then, it worked for me.